# Ktor is throwing a "Lost in ambiguity tie" error on GET requests

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have a project that was running on Kotlin 1.4.0 and Ktor 1.3.2, so I decided to try and upgrade my versions to Kotlin 1.4.30 and Ktor 1.5.1 (since I was also upgrading to Java 11 due to adoptopenJDK8 not having JavaFx).

When I finally fixed import issues and whatnot and ran my webserver, the first page opens correctly (it's mapped to route "/"), but the other GET requests throw a "Lost in ambiguity tie" error on the RoutingResolve class. Apparently when comparing the quality of registered selectors, the "/ping" one has the same value as "//", hence throwing the error. I have validated this behaviour Ktor 1.5.1 and 1.5.0. Versions 1.4.x throw coroutine errors.

My server configurations are declared as such:

```
fun serverConfiguration(controller: Controller): NettyApplicationEngine {
    SocketRoutes.controller = controller
    WebUIRoutes.controller = controller

    return embeddedServer(Netty, 9090) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            jackson {
                enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance()
                deactivateDefaultTyping()
            }
        }
        install(FreeMarker) {
            templateLoader = ClassTemplateLoader(this::class.java.classLoader, "templates")
            defaultEncoding = Charsets.UTF_8.toString()
        }
        install(CallLogging)
        install(Sessions) {
            cookie<UserPreferences>("preferences")
        }
        getRoutes(this)
    }
}
```

My Routes.kt

```
fun getRoutes(pipeline: Application): Routing {
    return Routing.install(pipeline) {
        trace { application.log.trace(it.buildText()) }
        static("/") {
            resources("web-static")
        }
        home()
        getTableBody()
        ping()
    }
}
```

And these routes themselves are on WebUIRoutes.kt

```
object WebUIRoutes {
    lateinit var controller: Controller
    fun Route.home() {
        get("/") {
            val session = call.sessions.get<UserPreferences>() ?: UserPreferences()
            call.sessions.set(session)
            val nrPages = calculateNrOfPages(session.nrElements)
            call.response.cookies["nrElements"]?.copy(value = "$nrPages")
            call.respondTemplate(
                "showCodes.ftl", mapOf(
                    "total" to nrPages, "nrElements" to session.nrElements,
                    "validateOnInput" to session.validateOnInput
                )
            )
        }
    }

    (...)

    fun Route.ping() {
        get("/ping") {
            if (controller.ping())
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            else
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        }
    }
}
```

So I have no idea what the hell is going on and I've found nothing online about migrating to newer versions of Ktor and related issues...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `resources` function adds a route with a wildcard under the `/` route and therefore the routing resolves it instead of the `/ping` route. You can just move the `static` function call to the end of `Routing` to make it work as you expect.

Comment: I'll try it and if it works, I'll accept the answer! Thanks for the help! So this changed in the latest versions of ktor? This was working on 1.3.2.

Comment: @Sidner there were several significant changes to routing since version 1.3.2 and probably one of them introduced a regression.